# REP-0606 unable to read linked file check link file format in oracle reports

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, file-read, oraclereports

I am reading a image file and showing it in Oracle reports 6i.  Below coding is for your reference.

```
function cf_imageFormula return Char is

out_file Text_IO.File_Type; 
image_1 varchar2(2000);`enter code here`

begin
  select   'Q:\sy\img\'||:pyempcde||'.' || 'jpg'  into image_1
from dual;


out_file :=Text_IO.Fopen('Q:\sy\img\'||:pyempcde||'.' || 'jpg', 'r'); 

return ('Q:\sy\img\'||:pyempcde||'.' || 'jpg');

exception 
when no_data_found then 
return('Q:\sy\img\no_image.jpg'); 
when others then 
return('Q:\sy\img\no_image.jpg');
end;
```

The image also showing successfully in report for the first record, from second record the subjected error is showing. Please help me with solution..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, image size might be the issue. Reports isn't capable of displaying (too) large images (in size, [KB], not *centimeters*). If that's the case, there's nothing much you can do about it, unless you resize images and make them much smaller (regarding what you've said - it displays only one image ... that's close to *nothing*).

Just wondering: how large are those images? How many of them are you supposed to display in the report?

Comment: I want to display more than 30 images and that is one image for each page.. each image size is nearly 1.2 M.

Comment: I presume that that's too large. I've had to print some *signed contracts*, where signature was a scanned image. For ~300 contracts, when the image was larger than 20 KB (KB! not MB), the report failed so I had to *shrink* image size. Try to do the same; there are tools (available on the Internet) that let you resize images *all-at-once*. See what happens. Don't forget to save a backup copy of the original images!

Comment: I made the report to call one image for one time.. thanks

Comment: Hi littlefoot, now I am trying to show only one image then also its showing the same error.. may be image size is more.. can we have any option to resize the image

Comment: It is done at operating system level; use any image viewer, it should have that capability.

Comment: without resizing the image i want to show it in report with the size fixed in report..